# What's the fastest way to use C/C++ in Python?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-extension, python-extensions

What is the fastest way to call C/C++ functions and use C++ classes?
There are various methods to do this such as Python Extension Module (Python.h), Cython, SWIG, Boost, and etc.

I've already implement C/C++ functions and C++ classes. Because performance is very important in my project.

So, I want to call C/C++ functions and use C++ classes in python with minimal modification of c/c++ code (or wrapping with no change of existing code). What is the best way?

Comment: No modification on the C++ side -> Cython; minor modification on the C++ side -> SWIG; C++ only solution -> Boost.

Comment: are you doing a lot of calculations or what? why not using C/C++ without Python?

Comment: If they are compiled into a shared object, [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) can be used.

Comment: Asking about fastest is a question that can rarely  be meaningfully answered. Fastest to do what? I think only experimentation with your specific use case can tell you that for sure. Also the methods with less runtime overhead will doubtless have larger development time overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the functions in C++, I suggest you create a dll or more and check how they can be called from python.
As far as I know there is a library in python for things like this named ctypes and it works like this:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}


import ctypes
a = ctypes.WinDLL ("path\\to\\mydll.dll")

result = a.sum(10,1)

print(result)
```